# Load multiple URLs at the same time

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have a list of resources which serve me XML feed. I need to loop through them and update database accordingly.

So imagine we have 100 URLs. I need to start fetching XML from them at the same time, then, after some time parsing of all XML feeds will be finished, and I need to catch this moment in order to update "Last refreshed time".

I use `simplexml_load_url` for the purpose of parsing XML.

Them most important thing is time issue, I tried fetching XMLs one-by-one and it took around 50 seconds for 20 URLs.

How can I achieve this? Number of URLs might be around 300-500.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just create an array at the start of your loop(?) and cache the unique identifier for each row as you go.  Then after all the parses are complete just run something like `UPDATE table SET lastModfied = 'some_datetime' WHERE unique_identifier IN (list, of, identifiers);`

Comment: LastModified should be the time after all 300-500 Urls updated. It's not the time of each url, it's "Hey, 300 url were updated at 15:03". The most important is how to fetch data simultaneously, kind of make it parallel

Comment: Right, that is what my suggestion would do.  `PHP` does not support asynchronous tasks so actually parsing all the files at the same time is not something you can do without somehow triggering each parse operation as a separate request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GuzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests) that can do the concurrent file processing. Much more efficient and fast if it fits your case.

Comment: Oh probably that's what I need. I also got an advice to use something called rolling curl, not sure about it though. Guzzle is included in Laravel by default. Will take a look soon and tell you the result, thanks :)

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452555/what-is-exactly-concurrency-in-guzzle please, if you can. I tried using guzzle, there are a lot of articles with a lot of ways to work with it, not sure I understand the difference between Pool and "Promise\settle($promises)->wait();". I decided to use Pool and now playing with it, it's faster then using simplexml_load_file, though I haven't yet parsed XML itself...

Comment: I will recommend using promises as it is asynchronous and probably do the trick to reduce your total processing time.